# SecurityContext is deprected in symfony 2.6

Tags: symfony-2.6

The service SecurityContext is deprectaed in SF 2.6
What is the right service should be used instead of securityContext in Symfony 2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Symfony 2.6, the SecurityContext class was split in the AuthorizationChecker and TokenStorage classes.

To retreive the user you can use:

```
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

To check authorization you can use:

```
if (false === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) { ... }
```

[More deatils](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements)